# Calculus maximum area problem. Struggling to form correct equations.

Tags: calculus

I am not sure where I'm going wrong with this question but I suspect it's to do with forming the initial equations - either that or I simply don't fully understand the question.

Question is as follows:

A farmer has a certain number of hurdles available and he decides to make two sheep folds with them, one a square fold and the other circular. Show that the total area enclosed by the hurdles is a maximum when a side of the square equals the diameter of the circle.

My line of attack, which seems to agree with that of the book in previous questions, has been as follows:

Let $x$ and $y$ represent the length of the side of the square and the diameter of the circle respectively.

Then:

Total perimeter $$P = 4x + \pi y$$
giving $$y = \frac{P -4x}{\pi} $$

Total area  $$A = x^2 + \frac{\pi y^2}{4}$$

Which upon substituting for $y$ gives:
$$A = x^2 + \frac{\pi(P - 4x)^2}{4\pi^2}$$

i.e. $$A = \frac{(4\pi + 16) x^2 - 8Px + P^2}{4\pi}$$ where $P$ is a constant.

I initially continued here and differentiated wrtx but a moments reflection will hopefully show why I will go no further here.

If area was to be graphed as a function of x, it would result in a positive parabola which obviously has a minimum value - this is what I meant when I originally stated that I perhaps don't understand the question. As a result of this my attempts appear to have been fruitless and I am unsure where I am going wrong. I should add this is an end of chapter question so may be more challenging than previous questions - see previous calculus question I posted if required.

Any helpful hints would be gratefully received. Hopefully my algebra is correct but apologies if there are any errors.

Finally, to cite the question, this is from Elementary Calculus and Coordinate Geometry by C G Nobbs 1948.

Many thanks in advance once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct so far. If $A=\frac{(4\pi+16)x^2-8Px+P^2}{4\pi}$, then taking the derivative and setting it equal to $0$ yields $0=\frac{(8\pi+32)x}{4\pi}-\frac{8P}{4\pi}$, or $(8\pi+32)x=8P$. Substitute the expression for $P$ and you get $8(4x+\pi y)=(8\pi+32)x$. Expand everything out and you get $32x+8\pi y =8\pi x +32x$. The $32x$, being present on both sides of the equation, can be cancelled, leaving the equality $8\pi y = 8\pi x$. Cancelling the common factor of $8\pi$ yields $y=x$, which is what you want to show. QED.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand now how to show $y=x$ but I still don't understand how this is a maximum. In the equation for area in terms of $x$, the coefficient of $x^2>0$. Therefore, differentiating and setting this equal to $0$ gives a minimum value for area and not a maximum. Think I must be missing a vital point here.